# ACF blocks not showing with Timber

Tags: wordpress, twig, timber

So I am getting my head around how Timber works, I'm getting the hang of that so now I want to now get my head around ACF and Twig.

Ive added the following to functions.php:

```
    add_action( 'acf/init', 'my_acf_init' );

function my_acf_init() {
    // Bail out if function doesn’t exist.
    if ( ! function_exists( 'acf_register_block' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Register a new block.
    acf_register_block( array(
        'name'            => 'example_block',
        'title'           => __( 'Example Block', 'your-text-domain' ),
        'description'     => __( 'A custom example block.', 'your-text-domain' ),
        'render_callback' => 'my_acf_block_render_callback',
        'category'        => 'formatting',
        'icon'            => 'admin-comments',
        'keywords'        => array( 'example' ),
    ) );
}
/**
 *  This is the callback that displays the block.
 *
 * @param   array  $block      The block settings and attributes.
 * @param   string $content    The block content (emtpy string).
 * @param   bool   $is_preview True during AJAX preview.
 */
function my_acf_block_render_callback( $block, $content = '', $is_preview = false ) {
    $context = Timber::context();

    // Store block values.
    $context['block'] = $block;

    // Store field values.
    $context['fields'] = get_fields();

    // Store $is_preview value.
    $context['is_preview'] = $is_preview;

    // Render the block.
    Timber::render( 'block/example-block.twig', $context );
}
```

This is the block file:

```
{#
/**
 * Block Name: Example block
 *
 * This is the template that displays the example block.
 */
#}

{% if is_preview %}
    <p>I will only appear in the editor.</p>
{% endif %}

<div id="example-{{ block.id }}" class="wrapper">
    <h1>{{ fields.title }}</h1>
    <p>{{ fields.description }}</p>
</div>
<style type="text/css">
    #testimonial-{{ block.id }} {
        background: {{ fields.background_color }};
        color: {{ fields.text_color }};
    }
</style>
```

Where am I going wrong? I have searched loads of documentation but I haven’t found anything and I'm starting to pull my hair out over it as it should be easy

Comment: Can you move the `my_acf_block_render_callback()` out of your `my_acf_init()` function?

Comment: @Gchtr Ah I see yes and if I do that I still don't see it on the front end though

Answer (score 0):

OK so this probably isn’t the best or maybe even correct way but I have finally got the ACF blocks to show on the frontend - yay!

I added the following to my fuctions.php:

```
add_filter('timber_context', 'bt_timber_add_to_context');
function bt_timber_add_to_context ($context) {
    // add current page content
    $context['page'] = Timber::get_post();

    return $context;
}
```

Whilst I would love to say I came up with the solution myself all credit goes to @Buttered_Toast ([found a solution](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/401125/timber-twig-post-content-returns-null-cant-create-acf-gutenberg-blocks)